# How to eject the CD Drive on Linux using C?

Tags: c, linux

I was reading through this [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) tutorial when I encountered a problem. I was trying to eject the CD-ROM drive using this code:

```
int fd = open(path_to_cdrom, O_RDONLY);

// Eject the CD-ROM drive
ioctl(fd, CDROMEJECT);

close(fd);
```

Then I try to compile this code and get the following output:

```
In file included from /usr/include/linux/cdrom.h:14,
                 from new.c:2:
/usr/include/asm/byteorder.h: In function ‘___arch__swab32’:
/usr/include/asm/byteorder.h:19: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘:’ token
/usr/include/asm/byteorder.h: In function ‘___arch__swab64’:
/usr/include/asm/byteorder.h:43: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘:’ token
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: system("/usr/bin/eject"); :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message you're seeing looks like something is wrong in your #include lines, not with the code you posted. I tried compiling [http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/listings/chapter-6/cdrom-eject.c](https://web.archive.org/web/20120515215300/http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/listings/chapter-6/cdrom-eject.c) and it compiles just fine.

Comment: So how do I fix my include files?

Comment: What compiler are you using? I took a look at /usr/include/asm/byteorder.h on my Linux box, and the line causing your error is inline assembly in a GCC specific syntax, so if you're using something other than GCC that might be the cause of your trouble.

Comment: @Laurence: No I'm using GCC and I also looked at `byteorder.h` and seen the inline assembly.

Comment: The link in this answer is dead. Can someone please update it?

Comment: @DynamiteReed It's available on archive.org. I updated the link in the answer to go to the archived copy.

Answer (score 6):

According to [this](http://leapster.org/linux/cdrom/), you need to specify O_NONBLOCK when opening the device, otherwise it won't work.

From that page:

`cdrom = open(CDDEVICE,O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK)`

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a `#include`, I think. Do you have:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/cdrom.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

Those are the ones in the example...

Answer (score 0):

In the previous examples the following includes are not needed.

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
```

Also as stated before you may need to open with O_NONBLOCK

You can find more options for interacting with the CDROM device in the header file located at '/usr/include/linux/cdrom.h' or here https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/cdrom.h

Also here is another example for opening and closing the CD tray with the mentioned changes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/cdrom.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Path to CD-ROM drive
    char *dev = "/dev/dvd";
    int fd = open(dev, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);

    if(fd == -1){
        printf("Failed to open '%s'\n", dev);
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("fd :%d\n", fd);

    // Eject the CD-ROM tray 
    ioctl (fd, CDROMEJECT);
    sleep(2);

    // Close the CD-ROM tray
    ioctl (fd, CDROMCLOSETRAY);
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The open syscall has some unwanted behaviours which must be handled by setting it to Not blocking ie O_NONBLOCK
Also check that you have included the  header file

```
#include <linux/cdrom.h>
```

Comment: #include<linux/cdrom.h>